# Is F/C chord a Hybrid ? How?

Tags: theory, chord-theory

I was reading a theory book few days ago and I saw that F/C is a Hybrid chord of C .But how ?? I could under stand if it's G/C or Dm/C but isn't F/C just a inverstion ??

Comment: I don't know about this "hybrid chord" business, but if F is the root, then it is an **F** in 2nd inversion (e.g. **Gm7/D - C7 - F/C**), and if C is the root then it is a **C6(sus4)** (e.g. **Dm7 - G7 - F/C - C**).

Comment: @DavidBowling what do you mean by in the root ? Are you talking about the bass note ?? You gave me 2 examples and I they kinda look the same. Could you explain it more clear ? Thanks

Comment: The root of the chord. C is the root of a C major triad, even if it is a **C/G** (2nd inversion). The point of the examples was that in the first one **F/C** is functioning as an **F** chord in the context of the chord progression, but in the second one **F/C** is functioning as a **C** chord in the context of the progression. In other words, **F/C** can function as an **F** in 2nd inversion, or it can function as a **C6(sus4)**, depending on the context.

Comment: [You might be interested](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/56851/which-note-is-designated-as-the-root-of-a-chord-and-is-that-designation-subje) in looking at [these related questions](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/7380/how-to-identify-the-root-note-of-a-chord).

Comment: It might help if you could quote the definition of a hybrid chord that appears **in your music theory book**. There are at least a couple different definitions for hybrid chord online, so it’s not well defined. If we see what’s in the book it would help us understand the logic.

Comment: @DavidBowling Oh I see ! Thanks for the answer ! So I think the answer is it depends on the context of the chord progression ! Thanks it really helped me out !

Answer (score 3):

Hybrid chord of C? It's written **F/C** so it's an **F** chord with a C bass - a second inversion.

Maybe C/F would be a 'hybrid' of C, but when it's a slash chord,and the note after the slash, played as the lowest note, is part of the main chord, it's an *inversion*.

Comment: Yes I understand what your saying.But from my book it says that F/C could also be a Hybrid of C.Maybe because we could see as Csus4 6 ?? And isn't C/F hybrid of F ? Because the bass note is the original chord in Hybrid chords ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it must just be a misprint. 
F/C is F major in 2nd inversion.

C/F would be a hybrid chord, C+4 (4th in bass).

Comment: **C/F** is not **Csus4** since it still has a 3rd in it; it would be a **Cadd11**

Comment: @DavidBowling my bad, just meant an add 4. Have edited in answer

Comment: Technically your nomenclature here reads “C augmented 4th”. It should read as David Bowling said.